# How to set a image source outside Component

Tags: image, qt, qml

I have a image showing up in a Dialog in my QML app, and I want to be able to change that image later on using onClicked, which I pass by a function to check if the variable I want in the new source URL is one of them I want.

I've tried just by using Image.source = "NEWURL" which is a no go. Also the id of the component the image is in, and the dialog like: id.source = "neurl" - no go.

How do I do that?

EDIT: Added more code; both the function and then listitm used to click. The image is a web image, and I want to have the conncectedUser value (which is a user name) inside the url.

Here is all the related code:

```
// Check if users is really a user, and if; show skin
function checkCurrentUser(currentUser) {
    console.debug('Debug: Check user "'+currentUser+'" if actually a user.')

    if (currentUser == "Ingen online") {
        currentUser = "Notch" // reset currentUser if pushed earlier
        console.debug('Debug: It was not a real user. Showing '+currentUser+' instead')
        Image.source = "http://blabla"+currentUser+"yesyes"
    }
    else {
        console.debug('Debug: It was a real user.')
        Image.source = "http://blabla"+currentUser+"yesyes"
    }
    return "http://blabla"+currentUser+"yesyes""
}

            // the dialog I want to show with a image
            Component {
                 id: userDialog
                 Dialog {
                     id: dialogueUser
                     title: i18n.tr("Image")
                     Image {
                         id: usersSkin
                         fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                         source: "URL"
                         sourceSize.height: 1200
                     }

                     Button {
                         text: i18n.tr("Close")
                         color: "red"
                         onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialogueUser)
                     }
                 }
                }

     // and then the list containting each link, which on click should show the user image
     ListView {
                    id: userList
                    width: parent.width
                    height: units.gu(5)
                    model: msmData
                    delegate: ListItem.Standard {
                        text: connectedUser
                        onClicked: {
                            console.debug('Debug: User clicked "'+connectedUser+'"')
                            checkCurrentUser(connectedUser)
                            PopupUtils.open(userDialog, userList)
                        }
                    }
                    header: ListItem.Header { text: i18n.tr("Connected Users") }
                    section.property: "type"
                    section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
                    section.delegate: ListItem.Header { text: i18n.tr(section) }
                }
```

Comment: `I've tried just by using Image.source = "NEWURL" which is a no go`

Can you please explain why ?

Comment: Hi Amit, well the image just wont show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was to just reset the variable in the image URL, and then show the dialog. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I will give it a try:

```
   Component 
   {
             id: userDialog
             Dialog 
             {
                 property int sourceState : 1
                 id: dialogueUser
                 title: i18n.tr("Image")
                 Image 
                 {
                     id: usersSkin
                     fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                     source: 1 == sourceState ? "OLDURL" : "NEWURL"
                     sourceSize.height: 1200
                 }

                 Button 
                 {
                     text: i18n.tr("Close")
                     color: "red"
                     onClicked: 
                     {
                        PopupUtils.close(dialogueUser)
                        dialogueUser.sourceState = 0                            
                     }
                 }
              }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to push a varible into the new URL based on the user click, which comes from a delegated XML list item.